# XPath query doesn't output any results

Tags: xml, dom, xpath, language-agnostic

Why don't I get any results using the XML and XPath code below?

This is actually PowerShell but I also tried it with [this online tool](http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/) but again: it output nothing!

**I think I'm totally overlooking something!**

```
[xml] $xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|AnyCPU">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x86">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|AnyCPU">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
"@;

Select-Xml "//ItemGroup" $xml | % {
    Write-Host $_.Node.GetType();
}
```

Comment: You are overlooking the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the default namespace.

Try `//*[local-name()='ItemGroup']`.

or `/*/*[local-name()='ItemGroup']`

or `/*/*`

All 3 of these should return `ItemGroup`.

Comment: Thank you very much! You don't know any easier method doing this in PowerShell, do you? Are there any abbreviations for it?

Comment: @ComFreek - Sorry I don't know anything about PowerShell. The only shortcut really is with XPath 2.0 and you can just use `*` for the prefix. (`*:ItemGroup`).

Comment: PowerShell (actually .NET) doesn't support XPath 2.0 :(

Comment: @ComFreek - You could use Saxon (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) which is available for .NET.

Comment: I will definitely have a look at it! Thanks for the link! BTW I can now accept your answer, the time period is over ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you had a prefix for your namespace, you could also do:

```
//prefix:ItemGroup
```

Comment: That XML is coming from a VS 2012 project file, I can't change the namespaces.